# Errors when importing IPFS while using React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, js-ipfs

I can not import IPFS because some Webpack errors. I do not really know how to fix them but after searching some information I think that is something about Webpack 5.
I did the following steps:

```
npx create-react-app test-app
cd test-app
npm install ipfs
```

Then I imported IPFS inside App.js:

```
import Ipfs from 'ipfs';
```

And when I execute `npm start` I get the following errors:

```
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:https" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.


Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:http" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.


Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:path" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.


Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:stream" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:url" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:util" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:worker_threads" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:zlib" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

Answer (score 0):

IPFS server is a NodeJS package. It won't work in the browser))

Comment: In case you're using some other package & this issue shows up. Just ensure that you're not importing the node package